# SQL Server table and index design for range seek

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

Our MS SQL Server database has a table T with the following fields and data:

```
Name |  Begin  |  End
-----------------------
A    |    3    |   6
B    |    2    |   4
C    |    4    |   5
...................
```

I usually use queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE 5 BETWEEN Begin AND End
```

to find records which contains the constant 5 between their "Begin" and "End" fields. The execution plan is to perform the whole table scan. How to design table structure and index to avoid table scan? Thanks!

Comment: Is there an index which includes begin and end dates?

Answer (score 2):

Create composite index on [Begin] and [End], including [name], then remove * from your query, replace with column name

```
 SELECT name, [begin],[end]
FROM T
WHERE 5 BETWEEN [Begin] AND [End]
```

The reason to do this is, just do one time non-cluster index seek, one time I/O read. 
Check the query plan again, it should be like this:
Index Seek (Non-cluster index....) 100%

Answer (score 1):

Add index which includes both Begin and End dates if one doesn't  exist.